# How do I get age in years, months and days by auto populating my form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-arithmetic

I want to auto fill my age in my form using a date-picker. It should populate the age in the form automatically when I put the birthday on the birth date form using date-picker then it will auto determine its age. For example my birthday is 10/17/1996 and today is 7/30/2017 so the form will auto populate like this:
20 years 9 months 13 days.

```
<!--html form-->
<input type="date" name="birthday"> 10/17/1996
<input type="text" name="Years"> 20 years
<input type="text" name="m"> 9 months
<input type="text" name="d"> 13 days

<!--script right here-->
function getAge(dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var Years = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        Years--;
    }
    return Years;
}
```

Comment: You should include something about what isn't working. What results are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="date"]').on('mouseout',function(){
    getAge($(this).val());
  });

});
function getAge(dateString) {
  if(dateString!==''){
    d1 = new Date();
    d2 = new Date(dateString);
    diff = new Date(
        d1.getFullYear()-d2.getFullYear(), 
        d1.getMonth()-d2.getMonth(), 
        d1.getDate()-d2.getDate()
    );
    
    $('input[name="Years"]').val(diff.getYear()+" Year(s)");
    $('input[name="m"]').val(diff.getMonth()+" Month(s)");
    $('input[name="d"]').val(diff.getDate()+" Day(s)");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="birthday"><br/><br/>
<input type="text" name="Years"><br>
<input type="text" name="m"><br>
<input type="text" name="d"><br>
```

Comment: It worked! Thankyou so much. Btw how do I auto input the html form? by years, months and age seperately? Btw thankyou I'll try to find a way :)

Comment: @JayzdeVera  means you want to output it in tree different input fields?

Comment: Yes how do I do it? document.form.write? something like that

Comment: Ohh okay :) sorry I am new to SO :) Thankyou so much!!

Comment: @JayzdeVera  no matter of sorry. glad to help you :):)